# Inconsistent printing of nested dict using pprint in Python

Tags: python, json, printing, console, pprint

I used `pprint` to pretty print a large nested `dict`:

```
import pprint
import json


with open('config.json', 'r') as fp:
    conf = fp.read()


pprint.pprint(json.loads(conf))



{u'cust1': {u'videotron': {u'temperature': u'3000K',
                           u'image_file': u'bloup.raw',
                           u'light_intensity': u'20',
                           u'size': [1920, 1080],
                           u'patches': [[94, 19, 247, 77],
                                        [227, 77, 293, 232],
                                        [77, 217, 230, 279],
                                        [30, 66, 93, 211]]}},
 u'cust2': {u'Rogers': {u'accuracy': True,
                        u'bleed': True,
                        u'patches': [[192,
                                      126,
                                      10,
                                      80],
                                     [318,
                                      126,
                                      10,
                                      80], ...
```

The 2nd level list `cust2.Rogers.patches` is unfold whereas `cust1.videotron.patches` is not. I'd like both **not** to be unfold, i.e. printed on the same line. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with two parameters: `width` and `compact` (the last one may be not available for Python 2).

`width` -- limits horizontal space.

And here is description for `compact`:

> If compact is false (the default) each item of a long sequence will be formatted on a separate line. If compact is true, as many items as will fit within the width will be formatted on each output line.

But as I understand you can't tell `pprint` anything about the structure of data and how you want specific elements to be printed.

Comment: thanks danil, I saw compact indeed but I work on py2. I was not thinking my problem came from limited `width`, that's it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### PrettyPrinter controls

The [*PrettyPrinter*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter) in the pprint module accepts various parameters to control output formatting:

- **indent**: the amount of indentation added for each recursive level
- **width**: the desired output width is constrained using the width parameter
- **depth**: the number of levels which may be printed
- **compact**: when true, as many items as will fit within the width will be formatted on each output line

### JSON alternative

The [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) itself has its own alternative to pprint using [*json.dumps*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) with the `indent` parameter set:

```
>>> print json.dumps(conf, indent=4)
{
    "cust2": {
        "Rogers": {
            "patches": [
                [
                    192, 
                    126, 
                    10, 
                    80
                ], 
       ...
```

### Specific Problem

> The 2nd level list cust2.Rogers.patches is unfold whereas cust1.videotron.patches is not. I'd like both not to be unfold, i.e. printed on the same line.

Neither of the above tools lets you directly solve your problem as specified.  To get exactly what you want, you will need to write some custom pretty printing code.